# Android - hide toolbar when edittext is focused

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus, toolbar

I have an edittext and it seems to be focused always, the keyboard doesnt appear because i added the next line:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

but the cursor is blinking.

The thing I want to do is that when the edittext is focused I need the toolbar to be hidden and when it is unfocused to show the toolbar

Answer (score 2):

Set `descendantFocusability = beforeDescendants` and `focusableInTouchMode = true` in your layout to avoid blinking cursor for your `EditText`. After that you need to:

```
loginLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            hideKeyboard(v, getApplicationContext());
            loginLayout.requestFocus();
            hideToolbar(); // your method to hide toolbar
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: but how do I unfocus the edittext when the key back of the phone is pressed?

Comment: `@Override` method `onBackPressed()`

Comment: Does not work. It is a real problem after tap on editText if  task bar is hidden.

Answer (score -1):

Simply get the focus of `EditText` and if it is true then call method

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

else if it is false called `getSupportActionBar().show();`

but you need to use `AppCompatActivity` for these two methods.